# boost::thread data structure sizes on the ridiculous side?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-thread, micro-optimization, systems-programming

Compiler: clang++ x86-64 on linux.

It has been a while since I have written any intricate low level system code, and I ussualy program against the system primitives (windows and pthreads/posix). So, the in#s and out's have slipped from my memory. I am working with `boost::asio` and `boost::thread` at the moment.

In order to emulate synchronous RPC against an asynchronous function executor (`boost::io_service` with multiple threads `io::service::run`'ing where requests are `io_serviced::post`'ed), I am using boost synchronization primitives. For curiosities sake I decided to `sizeof` the primitives. This is what I get to see.

```
struct notification_object
{
  bool ready;
  boost::mutex m;
  boost::condition_variable v;
};
...
std::cout << sizeof(bool) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(boost::mutex) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(boost::condition_variable) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(notification_object) << std::endl;
...
```

Output:

```
1
40
88
136
```

Forty bytes for a mutex  ?? ?? ? WTF ! 88 for a condition_variable !!! Please keep in mind that I'm repulsed by this bloated size because I am thinking of an application that could create hundreds of `notification_object`'s

This level of overhead for portability seems ridiculous, can someone justify this? As far as I can remember these primitives should be 4 or 8 bytes wide depending on the memory model of the CPU.

Comment: How can you construe that the types are 'bloated' for portability and not e.g. for functionality?

Comment: That might very well be, however, from the documentation the functionality does not go beyond what a system specific library allows you to do. If you think its due to functionality please make an argument for it as an answer :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you look at "size overhead" for any type of synchronization primitive, keep in mind that these *cannot* be packed too closely. That is so because e.g. two mutexes sharing a cacheline would end up in cache trashing (false sharing) if they're in-use concurrently, even if the users acquiring these locks never "conflict". I.e. imagine two threads running two loops:

```
for (;;) {
    lock(lockA);
    unlock(lockA);
}
```

and

```
for (;;) {
    lock(lockB);
    unlock(lockB);
}
```

You will see twice the number of iterations when run on two different threads compared to one thread running one loop *if and only if* the two locks are *not within the same cacheline*. If `lockA` and `lockB` are in the same cacheline, the number of iterations *per thread* will half - because the cacheline with those two locks in will permanently bounce between the cpu cores executing these two threads.

Hence even though the *actual data size* of the primitive data type underlying a spinlock or mutex might only be a byte or a 32bit word, the *effective data size* of such an object is often larger.

Keep that in mind before asserting "my mutexes are too large". In fact, on x86/x64, 40 Bytes is *too small* to prevent false sharing, as cachelines there are currently at least 64 Bytes.

Beyond that, if you're highly concerned about memory usage, consider that notification objects need not be unique - condition variables can serve to trigger for different events (via the `predicate` that `boost::condition_variable` knows about). It'd therefore be possible to use a single mutex/CV pair for a whole state machine instead of one such pair per state. Same goes for e.g. thread pool synchronization - having more locks than threads is not necessarily beneficial.

**Edit:** For a few more references on "false sharing" (and the negative performance impact caused by hosting multiple atomically-updated variables within the same cacheline), see (amongst others) the following SO postings:

- [false sharing in boost::detail::spinlock_pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037655/false-sharing-in-boostdetailspinlock-pool)
- [False sharing and pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331255/false-sharing-and-pthreads)
- [False Sharing and Atomic Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143676/false-sharing-and-atomic-variables)

As said, when using multiple "synchronization objects" (whether that'd be atomically-updated variables, locks, semaphores, ...) in a multi-core, cache-per-core config, allow each of them a separate cacheline of space. You're trading memory usage for scalability here, but really, if you get into the region where your software needs several millions of locks (making that GBs of mem), you either have the funding for a few hundred GB of memory (and a hundred CPU cores), or you're doing something wrong in your software design.

In most cases (a lock / an atomic for a specific instance of a `class` / `struct`), you get the "padding" for free as long as the object instance that contains the atomic variable is large enough.

Comment: Wow, there's a hell of a lot of background information in this post that I never would have been able to uncover on my own. +1 upboats.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand your answer, but I really don't see the relevance: You say yourself, that the size of a `boost::mutex` is not enough, to prevent false sharing, so this is obviously not the reason. Also, false sharing is not more relevant to a mutex than to any other object - would you suppose that any datatype should have at least 64 bytes to prevent that? You prevent false sharing, by adding stuff bytes between the objects, or by specifying the alignment, not by atrificially increasing the object's size.

Comment: @MikeMB: you're mixing two things up - the size of `boost::mutex` _not_ being large enough _is_ the reason why false sharing can occur - namely, when _two_ `boost::mutex` instances are [ at least partly ] within the same cacheline. And what do you think is the difference between "artificially increasing the object size" and "adding [stuff] bytes between" ? That's one and the same. What you do depends on your usecase. To tightly-pack arrays of locking primitives, you must increase the size. To co-host a 'protected' object with the locking primitive, pack both into the same cacheline.

Comment: @FrankH.:If I "artificially increase the object size", by adding stuff  bytes INTO the data type, the `sizeof` operator will return the size of the datastructure including the additional  stuff bytes. If I add bytes between two objects then that is not the case. Now, assuming, what you call the *effective data size* is what the `sizeof` operator returns (thats what the OP was asking after all), the fact, that `boost::mutex` is smaller than a cacheline rather indicates, that it was NOT stuffed.

Comment: Oh, and the reason I think it is better to not stuff the class itself is that this allows the user to decide, whether he needs to have to objects on a separate cacheline, which is - as you stated yourself - not always the case, or not, so why would you deny the user of your class that choice?

Answer (score 19):

On my 64-bit Ubuntu box, the following:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)=%ld\n", sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  printf("sizeof(pthread_cond_t)=%ld\n", sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
  return 0;
}
```

prints

```
sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)=40
sizeof(pthread_cond_t)=48
```

This indicates that your claim that

> This level of overhead for portability seems ridiculous, can someonee
>   justify this to me ? as far as I can remember these primitives should
>   be 4 or 8 bytes wide depending on the memory model of the CPU.

is quite simply not true.

In case you're wondering where the extra 40 bytes taken by `boost::condition_variable` come from, the Boost class uses an internal mutex.

In a nutshell, on this platform `boost::mutex` has exactly **zero** overhead compared to `pthread_mutex_t`, and `boost::condition_variable` has the overhead of the extra internal mutex. Whether or not the latter is acceptable for your application is for you to decide.

P.S. I would encourage you to stick to the facts and avoid using inflammatory language in your posts. I for one very nearly decided to ignore your post purely for its tone.

Comment: On windows, the variables you see in user code are likely to be handles refering to a larger data structure somewhere - make sure you take that into account.

Comment: Yes that makes sense I guess, Thanks. I guess I'll need to investigate why that much many bytes are needed for a mutex.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the implementation:

```
class mutex : private noncopyable
{
public:
    friend class detail::thread::lock_ops<mutex>;

    typedef detail::thread::scoped_lock<mutex> scoped_lock;

    mutex();
    ~mutex();

private:
#if defined(BOOST_HAS_WINTHREADS)
    typedef void* cv_state;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_PTHREADS)
    struct cv_state
    {
        pthread_mutex_t* pmutex;
    };
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_MPTASKS)
    struct cv_state
    {
    };
#endif
    void do_lock();
    void do_unlock();
    void do_lock(cv_state& state);
    void do_unlock(cv_state& state);

#if defined(BOOST_HAS_WINTHREADS)
    void* m_mutex;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_PTHREADS)
    pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_MPTASKS)
    threads::mac::detail::scoped_critical_region m_mutex;
    threads::mac::detail::scoped_critical_region m_mutex_mutex;
#endif
};
```

Now, let me strip the non-data parts and reorder:

```
class mutex : private noncopyable {
private:
#if defined(BOOST_HAS_WINTHREADS)
    void* m_mutex;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_PTHREADS)
    pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_MPTASKS)
    threads::mac::detail::scoped_critical_region m_mutex;
    threads::mac::detail::scoped_critical_region m_mutex_mutex;
#endif
};
```

So apart from `noncopyable` I see not much overhead that doesn't occur with system mutex's.

Comment: And noncopyable is elligible for the empty base class optimization.

Comment: +1 for bothering to look at the source, where the answer is obvious

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I comment this here, but I have no enough reputation for adding a comment.

@FrankH, cache trashing is not a good justification to make a data structure bigger. There are cache lines that can even have 128 bytes of size, it doesn't mean that a mutex must be so big.

I think programmers must be warned to separate synchronization objects in memory so they don't share the same cache line. What can be achieved by inserting the object in a big enough data structure, without bloating the data structure with unused bytes. On the other hand, inserting unused bytes can deteriorate the program speed, because the CPU has to fetch more cache line to access the same structure.

@Hassan Syed,
I don't think that mutexes were programmed thinking in this type of cache optimization. Instead, I think that this is the way they are programmed for supporting thinks like priority inheritance, nesting locks,... . As suggestion, if you need a lot of mutexes in your program, consider something like a pool (array) of mutexes and storing just an index in your nodes (of course taking care of memory separation). I let you to think on the details of this solution.